# Evidence Approximation -- Circular Logic?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, bayesian

**Background:**

Suppose that I observe some data $\mathbf{y} = [y_{1}, \ldots, y_{N}]^{T}$ at specific time points $\mathbf{t} = [ t_{1}, \ldots, t_{N}]^{T}$. I am assuming that my data can be modeled as:

$$ y_{n} = \sum_{m=1}^{M} w_{m} \phi_{m}\left( t_{n} \right) + \epsilon_{n} \; \forall n$$

where $ \epsilon_{n} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \beta^{-1} \right) $ are i.i.d.

If we assume that $ \mathbf{w} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \alpha^{-1} \mathbf{I})  $, where $\mathbf{w} = [w_{1}, \ldots, w_{M}]^{T}$, then we can find $\mathbf{w}$ by maximizing the posterior distribution:

$$ p(\mathbf{w} | \mathbf{y}, \mathbf{t}, \alpha, \beta) \propto p(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{t}, \mathbf{w}, \beta) p(\mathbf{w} | \alpha) $$

Doing the math, this gives us:

$$ p(\mathbf{w} | \mathbf{y}, \mathbf{t}, \alpha, \beta) = \mathcal{N}\left( \beta ( \alpha \mathbf{I} + \beta \Phi^{T} \Phi) \Phi^{T} \mathbf{y}, (\alpha \mathbf{I} + \beta \Phi^{T} \Phi)^{-1} \right)$$
where $\Phi_{m,n} = \phi_{m}(t_{n})$.

---

**The Problem**

In normal Bayesian inference, we would just pick an $\alpha$ and assume that we know $\beta$. However, using the 'evidence approximation', it is claimed that you can find both $\beta$ and $\alpha$ by maximizing:

$$ p(\mathbf{y} | \alpha, \beta) = \int p(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{t}, \mathbf{w}, \beta) p(\mathbf{w} | \alpha) d\mathbf{w}  $$

But my question is -- isn't that circular logic? Aren't we trying to find what we are assuming in the first place?

Assuming that we find these $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in this way, what will it do for us? Give us a better estimate of $\mathbf{w}$ via the posterior? But, how can we know that is actually a better estimate if we don't know what $\mathbf{w}$ is? Will choosing this $\mathbf{w}$ found using these optimal values minimize the mean square error more than if we used arbitrary values?

Also, suppose we find these parameter values -- what do they then represent? The "actual" prior and noise precision? Does it even make sense to say there is an "actual" prior?

In other words, what is the point of evidence approximation? Is it not circular logic? Where, when and why is it used?

Comment: Bayesian inference is really strange. Try to hide from it if you are not willing to _not_ ask questions...

Comment: @NeitherNor I could maybe understand why you would want to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ if your goal was to generalize the model for new data. Eg You assume that your current data is just a draw from some wider distribution that you will encounter more samples from later, and then these values may help you minimize the reconstruction error later. But what is the point of doing so in the asked about example? Or in general?

Comment: Your post is a bit hard to follow, thus I am just able to provide a rough guess: I think $\alpha$ and $\beta$ should have indices, i.e. there should probably be an $\alpha_{prior}$ and an $\alpha_{posterior}$, and all it's saying is that you are updating your believe based on the data.

Comment: @NeitherNor I see. I am just trying to follow Bishop's book -- and yea, it is hard to follow because I have no idea what I am talking about. I am quite confused!

Comment: @NeitherNor So what you are saying is, the evidence approximation provides a posterior estimate for the prior parameters? What good is that exactly?

Comment: Well, at the end you want to find the parameter of your model given that you have some data, right? Well, these parameter are $\alpha$ and $\beta$. So, what you do is to guess these parameters, then you run an experiment. There is then some information in the data, and the claim of bayesian inference is that you can use this information to update your believes.

Comment: @NeitherNor Ah okay. So using this kind of bayesian inference, the evidence approximation, I can update my beliefs about the noise and the weights based on the data. So would this mean I am 'less sensitive', in some way, to the data? Ie What would happen if I run the experiment again with my new prior parameter estimates?

Comment: The hope of bayesian inference is that, if you predict the outcome of this experiment with the updated parameters, the model is in better agreement with the actual outcomes of the experiment than if you use the original parameters.

Comment: @NeitherNor Okay, so I am updating my beliefs about these two parameters, which would then (hopefully) lead to a better fit. This must mean I am less sensitive to the data,  ie the prior becomes 'stronger' relative to the data (because we are transferring the information from the data to prior), right?

Comment: What exactly would become less sensitive to the data, and in which way?

Comment: @NeitherNor I think the estimates of $\mathbf{w}$ would. Because we are incorporating the information from the data into the prior. Therefore, why do we need the data anyway? Why can't we just say -- okay, now that we have the posterior $\alpha$, find the maximum of $p(w | \alpha)$ and call that the estimate of $\mathbf{w}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110470/discussion-between-neithernor-and-the-dude).